# converting infix to postfix

Tags: arithmetic

```
24 * (5 + 6) - 2
```

I am trying to find the post fix for this I got this so far

```
24 5 * 6 2 + -
```

is this correct or wrong I am quite struggling with these

Comment: you first do the parentes one so it will be 24 5 6 + * 2 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$24 * (5 + 6) - 2$

first you need to remember the order of operations, basicaly everything on () is made first
then multiplication, division and then sum and subctraction
so in that case 5 + 6 is made first
you start on 24
there a multiplication
but since there start of ( you don't do the operation yet
you get the sum 5 plus 6
wich lead to

24 5 6 +

now since ) ended and you have a subtraction wich is lower priority than * you do the multiplication

24 5 6 + *

now you just finish subtracting 2 leading to

24 5 6 + * 2 -

you answer is complet diferent from what you want

24 5 * 6 2 + -

leads to

$24*5 - (6 + 2)$

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia's [Postfix notation](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postfix_notation) gives an example of "4 * (5 + 8)" becoming "5 8 + 4 *". Using this concept, plus finishing with the $-2$ at the end, I believe one valid way to put $24 * (5 + 6) - 2$ into postfix notation would be

$$5 \; \, 6 \, + \, 24 \, * \, 2 \, \, - \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$